# Is there any way to make Bit.Trip Fate lefty-friendly?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, bit-trip-fate

I am lefthanded, and am trying to play Bit.Trip Fate on the 3DS, which requires me to use the analog stick with the left hand, and the stylus with my right. This is incredibly awkward, and borders on impossible - I have very little control with the stylus in my right hand.

Is there any way I can switch the controls so that it is easier (preferably a way that includes the ability to use the stylus in my left hand)? Or am I doomed to never be good at Bit.Trip Fate on the 3DS?

Comment: Bit.Trip Saga just has crummy controls as a 3DS game :( I ran into similar issues in Core (I wanted to use the circle stick not the awkwardly placed direction pad!)

Comment: *sigh* Well, that's craptacular. :( I was secretly hoping for some eventual support for the second stick addon thing or something. (Yeah, I'm a dreamer.)

Comment: this may sound a bit weird, but is it playable upside down? Also, I don't know about the 3DS but if homebrew works, there might be a way to swap left and right of the screen (rendering text hard to right though, but as a fellow lefty I claim we are better capable at reading mirrored text anyway, eh?)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I never thought of turning it upside down. I will have to try that!

Comment: @AshleyNunn so, how did it work out?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Once I got used to mentally inverting the movement, it worked awesome. I would totally accept this solution as an answer. It works quite well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may sound weird, but what about playing upside down?

Comment: This works quite well, once you get used to it.

Comment: @Wipqozn that's what being a lefty is all about ;-)